# How to make an element part of the other flow using position property?

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins, splidejs, scss-functions

Is there a way to achieve the solution to following problem:

I have a carousel markup and it follows the same HTML structure as mentioned below.

```
<div>
  // Contains the carousel slide
  <div>
   <ul>
    <li><img src={....} /></li>
    <li><img src={....} /></li>
    <li><img src={....} /></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  // Container for arrows
  <div class="carousel-arrows">
   <button class="carousel-arrow"> < </button> // left arrow
   <button class="carousel-arrow"> > </button> // right arrow
  </div>
   // Container for pagination
  <ul class="carousel_pagination">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  <ul>
</div>
```

Since the library, I'm using for the carousel follows this exact HTML structure I am unable to place the `ul` (pagination bullets) in between the left and right arrows.

I have tried using the `position` property as absolute to place the `ul` (pagination bullets) in between the arrows by setting a fixed `width` of `carousel-arrows` `div`, separating them with `space-between` and then placing `ul` in between them but I want the `carousel-arrows` `width` to be dynamic such that it can adjust based on increasing or decreasing number of bullets in `ul`.

[image: carosuel control]

When the bullets in pagination are less, then the width of the `carousel-arrow` should adjust itself accordingly and vice versa.

Is there a way to solve this using scss?

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that with SCSS alone I'm afraid. `position:absolute` removes the element from the normal document flow, and no space is created for it in the page layout. As far as `.carousel-arrows` is concerned, `.carousel_pagination` does not exist from a layout perspective.

You would need to use JavaScript to solve your problem, basing the `width` of `.carousel-arrows` on the `width` of `.carousel_pagination`.